# Unity3D & YamlDotNet Deserializing Data into Monobehaviour-derived classes

Tags: unity-game-engine, yamldotnet

I'm trying to serialize data into / from my classes, derived from `MonoBehaviour`, which cannot be created from client code (e.g., with the `new` keyword), but rather must be created by a Unity3D-specific method, `GameObject.AddComponent<T>()`. How can I use the `YamlDotNet` framework to populate my classes with values without having to create an adapter for each one? Is there some sort of built-in adapter that I can configure, such that YamlDotNet doesn't instantiate the class it's trying to serialize to?

A typical file might contain a mapping of items, e.g.,

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !invt! _PathwaysEngine.Inventory.
%TAG !intf! _PathwaysEngine.Adventure.
---

Backpack_01: !invt!Item+yml
  mass: 2
  desc:
    nouns: /^bag|(back)?pack|sack|container$/
    description: |
      Your backpack is only slightly worn, and...
    rand_descriptions:
    - "It's flaps twirl in the breeze."
    - "You stare at it. You feel enriched."

MagLite_LR05: !invt!Lamp+yml
  cost: 56
  mass: 2
  time: 5760
  desc:
    nouns: /^light|flashlight|maglite|lr_05$/
    description: |
      On the side of this flashlight is a label...

      (Type "light" to turn it on and off.)

...
```

Where the tags are the fully specified class names of my Items, e.g., `PathwaysEngine.Inventory.Lamp+yml`, `PathwaysEngine` is the namespace I use for my game engine code, `Inventory` deals with items & whatnot, and `Lamp+yml` is how the compiler denotes a nested class, `yml` inside `Lamp`. `Lamp+yml` might look like this:

```
public partial class Lamp : Item, IWearable {
    public new class yml : Item.yml {
        public float time {get;set;}
        public void Deserialize(Lamp o) {
            base.Deserialize((Item) o);
            o.time = time;
        }
    }
}
```

I call `Deserialize()` on all objects that derive from `Thing` from `Awake()`, i.e., once the `MonoBehaviour` classes exist in the game. Elsewhere, I've already created a pretty complicated `Dictionary` filled with objects of type `Someclass+yml`, and then `Deserialize` takes an instance of the real, runtime class `Someclass` and populates it with values. There's got to be a cleaner way to do this, right?

How can I:

1. Tell the `Deserializer` what my classes are?
   See the second edit for a good solution for the above issue
2. Get the data without it attempting to create my `MonoBehaviour`-derived classes?

**Edit**: I've since worked at the problem, and have found out a good way of dealing with custom data (in my particular case of trying to parse regexes out of my data, and having them not be considered strings & therefore, un-castable to regex) is to use a `IYamlTypeConverter` for that particular string. Using YamlDotNet with Unity3D `MonoBehaviour`s, however, is still an issue.

**Another Edit**: The above examples use a pretty ugly way of determining types. In my case, the best thing to do was to register the tags first with the deserializer, e.g.,

```
var pre = "tag:yaml.org,2002:";
var tags = new Dictionary<string,Type> {
    { "regex", typeof(Regex) },
    { "date", typeof(DateTime) },
    { "item", typeof(Item) }};
foreach (var tag in tags)
    deserializer.RegisterTagMapping(
        pre+tag.Key, tag.Value);
```

Then, I use the `!!tag` notation in the `*.yml` file, e.g.,

```
%YAML 1.1
---

Special Item: !!item
  nouns: /thing|item|object/
  someBoolean: true

Start Date: !!date 2015-12-17

some regex: !!regex /matches\s+whatever/

...
```

Comment: Usually serialization frameworks have some custom way to initialize stuff. I have never used yaml but if there is no way to solve this best might be to use the MonoBehaviour as a wrapper around another class.

You only serialize the inner class and then setup the MonoBehaviour yourself

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'm doing with the nested `yml` classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom implementation of `IObjectFactory` to the constructor of the `Deserializer` class. Every time the deserializer needs to create an instance of an object, it will use the `IObjectFactory` to create it.

Notice that your factory will be responsible for creating instances of **every** type that is deserialized. The easiest way to implement it is to create a decorator around `DefaultObjectFactory`, such as:

```
class UnityObjectFactory : IObjectFactory
{
    private readonly DefaultObjectFactory DefaultFactory =
        new DefaultObjectFactory();

    public object Create(Type type)
    {
        // You can use specific types manually
        if (type == typeof(MyCustomType))
        {
             return GameObject.AddComponent<MyCustomType>();
        }
        // Or use a marker interface
        else if (typeof(IMyMarkerInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
             return typeof(GameObject)
                 .GetMethod("AddComponent")
                 .MakeGenericMethod(type)
                 .Invoke();
        }
        // Delegate unknown types to the default factory
        else
        {
            return DefaultFactory(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is helpful, my problem is that I want to place my items and whatnot in the editor, so they exist in the scene already, with my classes already added as components. This might make the hack I'm using necessary.

This will probably be helpful to people anyways, I might just accept this answer and revise my question, ask another if I can't figure it out, etc.

Thanks for your help, either way!